# how do i call javascript function (web page) from android?

Tags: javascript, android

i have page contains javascript function in web page...

```
function callFromAndroid(varName)
{
 alert("call from android activated by " + varName);
}
```

i want call javascript function callFromAndroid() from android...

Is this possible?

Please explain how it can be done or point me to a resource where I can find such information.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Given a `WebView` named `wv`, call:

```
wv.loadUrl("javascript:callFromAndroid("+whateverYourVarValueIsAsJavaScriptLiteral+")");
```

The string passed to `loadUrl()` needs to be a `javascript:` scheme URL, with the literal source code you wish to invoke after the colon. This follows the same pattern as with [bookmarklets](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Bookmarklets).

Comment: i mean,i have javascript function in internet http://mydomain.com/index.php..and android is the client..i want pass value from android device and send to that page..

Comment: @ltvie: Write an Android app that uses a `WebView` to serve as your "client", then use the recipe I have in my answer.

Comment: sorry, i understand with your answer..i new android develop..but as known a webView located in android device?not in webserver?

Comment: @ltvie: "a webView located in android device?" -- yes. "not in webserver?" -- correct.